# Two Jquery for the same input box

Tags: jquery, text, replace, count

I am trying to limit the box to 8 words, But also replace Space with "comma Space" 
Can someone advise how I can do this please, I can either get the word count working or the space replace working, but not both.

Thank you

Here is my HTML

```
 <input name="input_4" type="text" id="input_10_4" size="100" />
```

and Here is my Jquery

```
jQuery("#input_10_4").keyup(function() {
  var textValue = $(this).val();
  textValue = textValue.replace(/ /g, ", ");
  $(this).val(textValue);
});
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  $("#input_10_4").keyup(function() {

    var content = $("#input_10_4").val(); //content is now the value of the text box
    var words = content.split(/\s+/); //words is an array of words, split by space
    var num_words = words.length; //num_words is the number of words in the array
    var max_limit = 8;
    if (num_words > max_limit) {
      alert("Exceeding the max limit");
      var lastIndex = content.lastIndexOf(" ");
      $("#input_10_4").val(content.substring(0, lastIndex));

      $('#remainingChars').text('Limit Exceeding');
      return false;
    } else {
      $('#remainingChars').text(max_limit + 1 - num_words + " words remaining");
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I would do this. It's not exactly like you wanted, but IMHO its a better user experience.

```js
// this timer function allows us to wait till the user is done typing,
//  rather than calling our code on every keypress which can be quite annoying
var keyupDelay = (function(){
  var timer = 0;
  return function(callback, ms){
    clearTimeout (timer);
    timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
  };
})();  

$('#input_10_4').keyup(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    // use our timer function
    keyupDelay(function(){
       // user has stopped typing, now we can do stuff 
       var max_limit = 8;
       var words = $this.val().trim().replace(/,/g, ' ').replace(/,?\s+/g, ' ').trim().split(' ');
       
       words = words.slice(0, max_limit); // get all the words up to our limit
       console.log(words);
       var wordString = words.join(', '); 
       $this.val(wordString);
       var remainingWords = max_limit - words.length;
       $('#remainingChars').text('Words remaining: '+remainingWords); 
    }, 800 ); // number of milliseconds after typing stops, this is equal to .8 seconds
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <input name="input_4" type="text" id="input_10_4" size="100" />
 <br>
 <div id="remainingChars"></div>
```